# Speculative tasks in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

New tasks in hadoop always have higher priority than speculative tasks.

Can anyone tell me how and where I can change this priority?

Comment: can you please elaborate more on the issue that you face? perhaps this post will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164886/hadoop-speculative-task-execution

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop `Speculator` uses a `Estimator` for estimating the run time of a task.

One of the main configuration parameters to control the speculative execution is: `mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold` (defined in mapred-site.xml and by default set to `1.0`).

The definition of this parameter says:

> The number of standard deviations by which a task's ave progress-rates
>   must be lower than the average of all running tasks' for the task to
>   be considered too slow.

It means, progress rate of each task is compared to the "mean progress rate" of all the other tasks in the job and multiplied with the value of `mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold`.

Let me explain this with example:

Let's assume there are 5 map tasks. Average progress rate is 70%. 
And value of `mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold` is set to 1.0.

Let's assume 1 of the map tasks is running slow and its progress rate is 50%. Since (70 x `mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold`) = (70 x 1.0) = 70%.
So, 50% is less than 70%, hence this map task will be scheduled for speculative execution (assuming `mapreduce.map.speculative` is set to `true`).

So, I guess to enable aggressive speculation, you need set this `mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold` to a higher value.

But, even after enabling aggressive speculation, you won't be able to start the redundant tasks immediately after the original task starts. Because Speculative Execution will come into picture only after some of the the tasks have started and if any of the current task is lagging behind (`Estimator` will give this input to the `Speculator`). So, maybe, you have to change the `Speculator` class (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.speculate.Speculator`) to achieve it.

But, it is recommended not to use this aggressively, since it could starve other jobs (if the same job occupies too many map/reduce slots due to speculative execution).

Please check this article by QuBole on the same: http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/hadoop/hadoop1/speculation.html