# How many mappers will run?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

I have this query.
lets say i have 3 datanode+nodemanager(clusters). we have replication factor of 3. At first cluster we got 4 blocks, so by default 4 mappers will run parallelly on first cluster. 
then as we have replication factor of 3, we ll have 12 mappers running in beginning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of block depends on file size. If you have 1gb of file that makes 8 blocks (of 128 mb).

So now all 8 blocks will be replicated three times by following [data locality and rack awareness](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html#Replica+Placement%3A+The+First+Baby+Steps) - but it doesn't mean all 24 (8 x 3) blocks will be processed when you run any job against this file. Replication is for to recover from disk failures type of scenarios.

So to answer your questions:

Number of mappers = number of input splits(in most cases number of blocks).

There will be only 8 mappers running on cluster. Hadoop will decide on which node these mappers need to be run based on data locality - at closest  block location in cluster(node).

There will be different case if speculative execution is enabled for the cluster - [hadoop-speculative-task-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164886/hadoop-speculative-task-execution)